# I need shell script inorder to fetch the ip of services deployed on kubernetes cluster

Tags: json, bash, shell, kubernetes, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am creating a release definition in VSTS where i need to fetch just the external ip of the service which is getting deployed using **Shell Script**. I am able to do it  from command line but not from VSTS release definition. I have got the JSON stored in a variable which consists of the IP. I need to fetch the IP from this JSON.

Or let me know if their is any **command for kubernetes** which will return just the external ip of the deployed services and not any other information.

Comment: SO is not a kubernetes support site, and this question is not related to programming.

Comment: I have seen some other people also has asked questions on kubernetes deployment. So what is wrong in that if i asked a question on kubernetes. This site is made to solve the problems that people face during their daily job tasks. I do not think i have done anything wrong asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a service of type `LoadBalancer`:

```
kubectl get svc <your_service> -ao jsonpath='{..ip}'
```

Comment: @VatanBansal If it worked you could consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: I am still facing one issue. Kubernetes is taking a lot of time to assign the external ips. But i need to fetch the ip as soon as service get deployed during VSTS release. If the ip is not assigned it will return a blank value. What should i do in this case.

Comment: @VatanBansal you can run the command in shell script using a loop and timeout. Try it and open a new question including your solution attempt in case of issues.

Comment: And what should be the timeout period because the ips are not getting assigned even after one day

Comment: @VatanBansal Open a new question for different topics. You should also care to accept/ upvote answers as a sign of respect to people who spend their time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function readJson {  
  UNAMESTR=`uname`
  if [[ "$UNAMESTR" == 'Linux' ]]; then
    SED_EXTENDED='-r'
  elif [[ "$UNAMESTR" == 'Darwin' ]]; then
    SED_EXTENDED='-E'
  fi; 

  VALUE=`grep -m 1 "\"${2}\"" ${1} | sed ${SED_EXTENDED} 's/^ *//;s/.*: *"//;s/",?//'`

  if [ ! "$VALUE" ]; then
    echo "Error: Cannot find \"${2}\" in ${1}" >&2;
    exit 1;
  else
    echo $VALUE ;
  fi; 
}
NAME=`readJson package.json name` || exit 1;  
# $NAME is "sample-project"
```

[Read a JSON Value in Bash](http://dailyraisin.com/read-json-value-in-bash/)

You can output the variable value to a JSON file by calling `echo {variable} > test.json`.